# Obtaining queryset based on unrelated models

Tags: django, django-models

I've got the following models. I need to obtain a queryset of orders where the user's userprofile.setupstatus == 1. Is this possible or should I just add a foreign key field on the Order model to the UserProfile?

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserCheckout, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class UserCheckout(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)                                    
    setupstatus = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is surely possible with [Django ORM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/)

Your query should look somewhat like this

```
Order.objects.filter(user__user__userprofile__setupstatus=1)
```

Comment: This skips over the UserCheckout model though, I think

Comment: As per your question, you didn't explain the need of UserCheckout model.
If it's needed, it can also be added in the filter.

Comment: The to get user, you have to use UserCheckout. Have a look at the relationships :)

Comment: Just in case you want to know what objects are related to a particular object in Django, just open shell using python manage.py shell, get that object using ORM and do a dir(obj), that helps a lot. :)